# Ultra low power configuration for a microcontroller switch?

Tags: switches, low-power

I have a project that is very low power (>10uA idle), and I'd like to have a reed switch input to give me a digital indication of a certain system state.

I can't guarantee which state the switch will be in for the majority of the time, so what is the lowest power way to implement a switch in this case? Ideally it would draw less than 1uA on average.

If possible I'd like to use one pin on the microcontroller since GPIO is limited.

Comment: wait, do you want to *actuate* or *read out* the reed switch?

Comment: I want to read the switch, sorry for the lack of clarity, I assumed it was obvious.

Comment: @Neil_UK yeah, even seemingly simple questions like these would immensely benefit from having a schematic.

Comment: Clarified. It's an input.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to "test" the state of a reed switch (open or closed) then drive it with (say) 10 uA from an IO line via a suitable resistor and read the signal coming back. Once read, turn off the driving signal. Keep duty cycle low to maintain < 1uA average consumption.

Have the reed switch grounded on one pin and read back the state on the other pin (the junction of the reed switch and suitable resistor).

The "suitable resistor" might be between 10 kohm and 1 Mohm depending on the wetting current needed by the reed contact.

Answer (score 0):

I have used an STM32L011 in a power constrained device. I've put it to suspend mode with RTC (to do something periodically) without RAM retention and connected a pushbutton to one of its wake pins (button from Vcc to wake, as they are pulled down internally in suspend). Consumption in suspend mode was around 1,7uA ([measured with this probe](http://www.cmicrotek.com/uCP.htm)) **with RTC running**. After exiting suspend mode the MCU basically resets, so I have used RTC backup registers to keep state of my application.